# Bad North Items

Tags: bad-north

I just picked up the game [Bad North](https://store.steampowered.com/app/688420/Bad_North/) every now and then it looks like the game awards me an item like "war horn", but I haven't seen any indication or tutorial on where they go after the battle or how to consume / use them.

Can anyone with knowledge able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! You can review and equip your items when your on the commander inspection screen. Just note that when you equip an item to a commander it cannot be removed.